# How to have two players on one keyboard in Monaco?

Tags: linux, keyboard, monaco

I've found [a thread](http://www.pocketwatchgames.com/forums/index.php?topic=1102.0) that explains how to do it. It involves simply downloading a couple of files, placing them in the appropriate folder and running the game.

However, I can't make it work on Linux. Naturally, I've adapted the instructions and placed the files at `~/.local/share/Steam/SteamApps/common/Monaco`, but I can't get this to work.

I also have an Xbox 360 wired gamepad plugged in. I have tried setting it as Player 1 or Player 2 and keyboard as 1, 2, 3 or 4, but nothing seems to work.

Actually, I'm starting to think the thread solution is not gonna work at all because one of those files is a `.dll`, which AFAIK will not work on Mac or Linux.

Comment: Have you tried unplugging the gamepad? Games sometimes do stupid things when they detect one of those.

Comment: @kotekzot, just did, same result. And in any case, I want it to have three players so I can get "Play it again, Sam". :)

Comment: If you're just interested in the achievement, you can use Steam Achievement Manager to unlock it.

Comment: Oh, no, that's no fun at all. I wanna earn my badges.

Comment: The multi-keyboard solution created in that thread is Windows-only.

Comment: Haven't gotten around to playing this one yet, so not sure if this would work... but if the game allows multiple players on *same* keyboard, then a workaround you could try is to use a feature in proton/wine to disable SDL which will prevent the controller being "seen" by the game and then use an external program such as antimicro / antimicrox to map the controller to P2's keyboard controls. I did something similar with Beyond Good and Evil [here](https://github.com/zpangwin/antimicro-profiles/tree/master/beyond-good-and-evil) to disable the native mappings to prevent conflicts with antimicro